# Parse JSON array in c# to read array collection inside json

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, json, c#-3.0

I have a below Jason format in which the Claims will be a array collection now I need to read all the Claims(which is a collection in below json) related to the policyid from c# , could anyone help me resoling it

```
{
                "ClaimList": [{
                                "Claims": ["CL8901"],
                                "PolicyID": "W1234sd",
                                "ClaimsCount": 1
                }, {
                                "Claims": ["CL3456", "CL1234"],
                                "PolicyID": "T1234sd",
                                "ClaimsCount": 2

                }, {
                                "Claims": ["CL1321"],
                                "PolicyID": "C1234sd",
                                "ClaimsCount": 1
                }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string json = Util.ReadLine<string>();
    JObject.Parse(json).SelectToken("ClaimList").Select(cl => new
    {
        PolicyId = cl.SelectToken("PolicyID"),
        Claims = cl.SelectToken("Claims").ToObject<List<string>>()
    }).Dump();
```

Linqpad code 
http://share.linqpad.net/vqoav5.linq

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you need, do the following:

1. Follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708070/how-do-i-create-a-dto-in-c-sharp-asp-net-from-a-fairly-complex-json-response) to create C# classes for your json
2. Use [NewtonSoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) NuGet library to deserialize the JSON to C# objects
3. Perform whatever processing you need on the deserialized items

Here is some code once you have done the above:

```
var claims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>("YourJsonHere");
IEnumerable<Claimlist> claimsForPolicy= 
    claims.ClaimList.Where(x => x.PolicyID == "whateverYouNeed");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the Json.NET library ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/)), this is pretty straightforward. First make sure you have a `Claim` class that has the structure of those inner objects in your JSON:

```cs
class Claim
{
    public List<string> Claims { get; set; }
    public string PolicyID { get; set; }
    public int ClaimsCount { get; set; }
}
```

Having that class available, you can use Json.NET to do something like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

// ...

string yourJson = getYourJsonStringSomehow();
var claimsDict =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<Claim>>>(yourJson);
```

That will produce a `Dictionary` with one key: "ClaimsList", and the value will be a `List` of your `Claim` objects:

```
var claimsList = claimsDict["ClaimsList"];
var firstClaim = claimsList[0];
Console.WriteLine(firstClaim.PolicyID);
// Should print W1234sd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, first lets create a Json class for your json data:

```
public class JsonDoc
{
    //I am adding an index on constructor for looping purposes
    public JsonDoc(string json, int index)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jResult = jObject["ClaimList"];
        Claims = jResult[index]["Claims"].ToObject<string[]>();
    }

    //This constructor will return the number of count under ClaimList node
    public JsonDoc(string json)
    {
        JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        JToken jResult = jObject["ClaimList"][0];
        intCount = jResult.Count();
    }

    private string[] Claims { get; set; }
    public int intCount { get; set; }
}
```

Then to use this class for your Json data, first add a reference of [Newtonsoft Json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
```

Then on your sample data, I read all the data via file using StreamReader, loop on it and put all the data under a List:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Folder\myjson.json"))
        {
            string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
            JsonDoc jSon = new JsonDoc(json);

            //This will get the length of the array under ClaimList node
            int intCount = jSon.intCount;


            List<JsonDoc> lstResult = new List<JsonDoc>();
            for (int x = 0; x < intCount; x++)
            {
                lstResult.Add(new JsonDoc(json, x));
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is a List of JsonDoc class with array of string as part of property. This array of string is the result on your Claims Node. This **JsonDoc** class contains property **Claims** which is a string array which contains your Claims node:

[image]