# C#, Deserialize json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json like the example bellow and I'm using C# with json.net.
I'm trying to deserialize this json into a object, but it's not working.

```
{
    "classes": [{
        "id": 1,
        "mask": 1,
        "powerType": "rage",
        "name": "Warrior"
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "mask": 2,
        "powerType": "mana",
        "name": "Paladin"
    }, {
        "id": 3,
        "mask": 4,
        "powerType": "focus",
        "name": "Hunter"
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "mask": 8,
        "powerType": "energy",
        "name": "Rogue"
    }, {
        "id": 6,
        "mask": 32,
        "powerType": "runic-power",
        "name": "Death Knight"
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "mask": 2048,
        "powerType": "fury",
        "name": "Demon Hunter"
    }]
}
```

1) I created a class:

```
public class ClassJson
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "classes")]
    public Class Class { get; set; }
}
```

2) The second class:

```
public class Class
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "powerType", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PowerType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I call the Api, get the json and I simply call `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ClassJson>>(json)`. Nothing happens, no errors.

Can someone give me a tip in order to structure better the classes?

Comment: `classes` in given json represents an array. So you need to declare property as `public Class[] Classes { get; set; }`. That should work.

Comment: Try JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ClassJson>(json). classes is a collection property.

Comment: I think 'classes' should be a `List<Class>`, or another collection type. Since it is an array in json.

Comment: You can actually just use `IEnumerable<Class>`, Newtonsoft will figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead because `classes` is supposed to be an array:

```
public class ClassJson
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "classes")]
    public Class[] classes { get; set; }
}
```

You do not need to write the classes to represent JSON manually. Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708070/how-do-i-create-a-dto-in-c-sharp-asp-net-from-a-fairly-complex-json-response) on how to create a class representation of your JSON.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, I didn't know about this shortcut to create classes given a json !