# Parsing data from json in C#

Tags: c#, json, parsing, xamarin.android

I successfully got data to `var content`
The code how I did it:

```
public async void FetchAsync()
{
    var client = new RestClient("http://api.locopal.com");
    var request = new RestRequest("/countries", Method.POST);
    var response = client.Execute(request);
    var content = response.Content;
    var responseCountries = JArray.Parse(JObject.Parse(content)[""].ToString());
}
```

But in line: `var responseCountries = JArray.Parse(JObject.Parse(content)[""].ToString());` I got An unhandled exception occured.
This is the data from `var content`:
[image]

Countries from here need to be write down to list.

Comment: What is the exception? You're passing empty string in `JObject.Parse(content)[""]` that could have been the reason?

Comment: If you face difficulty modelling your JSON in C#, you can use http://json2csharp.com/ in future.

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708158/4228458) on how to do what you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare a class like the following

```
public class Country
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; } 

    [JsonProperty("nicename")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize the json as below:

```
var responseCountries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Country>>(content);
```

Comment: `var responseCountries = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<RootObjectCountries>>(content);` worked for me

Comment: @S.Koshelnyk Yeap it needs `DeserializeObject`. Thanks !

Comment: Looks like Newtonsoft.Json will deserialize to a Collections.Generic.List if you provide IEnumerable as a generic type argument. IMO, you should just say `DeserializeObject<List<Country>>` for clarity and performance.

Answer (score 3):

You should [deserialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm) the JSON into an object. You can create a POCO object with the properties from the JSON.

Example:

```
public class Country
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nicename")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Follow same casing as in JSON