# How can get data from Json array in c#?

Tags: c#, json

I want to get data from this JSON array.
I use some keywords but I get the error every time, How can I get the data?

```
JArray test1 = JArray.Parse(jsondata);
string ids = test1["id"];
```

if i write "id" so i'm not get ans 11

```
{[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "userName": null,
    "passWord": null,
    "email": "someone@gmail.com",
    "mobile": "9898989898",
    "fullName": "Ramesh Sharma",
    "location": "Rajkot",
    "city_id": 1
  }
]}
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON. Are you sure that's your JSON, without a property?

Comment: _"I get the error every time"_ What is the exact error message?

Comment: I am getting this type of json data,                                                                      "[{\"id\":11,\"userName\":null,\"passWord\":null,\"email\":\"someone@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"9423422882\",\"fullName\":\"Ramesh Sharma\",\"location\":\"Rajkot\",\"city_id\":1}]"                             but for removing '\' i used  `var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(responseString);` this code then i get that type of array

Comment: @kiran you can use the validator [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) to see that your JSON is invalid. You ought to work on fixing that first.

Comment: my proper data is this `"[{\"id\":11,\"userName\":null,\"passWord\":null,\"email\":\"someone@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"9423422882\",\"fullName\":\"Ramesh Sharma\",\"location\":\"Rajkot\",\"city_id\":1}]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each value like this, then it is upto you which value you need to choose.

```
    foreach (JObject content in test1.Children<JObject>())
    {
          string Id = content["id"].ToString();
          string email = content["email"].ToString();
    }
```

By the way below is your correct formatted Json.

```
[{"id":11,"userName":null,"passWord":null,"email":"someone@gmail.com","mobile":"9423422882","fullName":"Ramesh Sharma","location":"Rajkot","city_id":1}]
```

Comment: Thanks Prany, I  get answer from foreach loop but it will iterate everytime and and I will get value but I want specific values e.g fullName,id,cityid . can you please help me how i get this

Comment: @kirangirase  Cheers Mate

Answer (score 1):

In a comment to your question you said your JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "id": 11,
    "userName": null,
    "passWord": null,
    "email": "someone@gmail.com",
    "mobile": "9898989898",
    "fullName": "Ramesh Sharma",
    "location": "Rajkot",
    "city_id": 1
  }
]
```

Create C# classes for your JSON as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42708158/4228458) and you will get these classes:

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public object userName { get; set; }
    public object passWord { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string fullName { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public int city_id { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize it like this:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJSON);
```

Comment: I understand it is a tool, but oh my those names suck big time

Comment: @camiloterevinto Agree. Thats why it should be changed so it makes sense in your domain.

Comment: @kirangirase What do you mean *model* class? I dont understand what you are saying. Sorry.