# How do i convert this JSON object into C# code?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert a JSON object from JavaScript into C#. I want to be able to access it like you would in normal JavaScript, like this: `letters.property[arrayindex]`.

I tried some of those online converters, which gave me the class, but some of the properties of the object are invalid; I basically have one property for every letter of the alphabet, and some of the punctuation characters, like the semicolon, which C# won't let me use as an object property.

Here is the JSON object I want to convert:

```
 {
            "-": [

        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "1", "1", "1", "1", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
        ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]



   ],
}
```

That is just one property of the object, there are many after that as well that are similar to this one. How do I convert this?

Comment: Have you tried Json.NET ?

Comment: Did you try https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonArray.htm ? That should do the trick.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a Dto in C# Asp.Net from a fairly complex Json Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708070/how-do-i-create-a-dto-in-c-sharp-asp-net-from-a-fairly-complex-json-response)

Comment: No, but I tried NewtonSoft.Json.

Comment: There's not any way to have a semicolon as a property name. The closest you could do is to deserialize it as a dictionary.

Comment: ah. So I guess I'll have to do something else for the semicolon.

Comment: The first character of a property has to be a letter or underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to deserialize to something like this:

```
var charSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<char, int[][]>>(json);
var valueSet = charSet['-'];
```

Comment: So if I do  JArray.Parse(String), will that fill in for the json in the code?

Comment: For `json`  I used what you had posted in the OP, minus the trailing comma. So it should work for you. Just use the raw string not `JArray.Parse`

Comment: so I did `Dictionary<char, int[][]> charSet = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<char, int[][]>>(json); Bot.letters = charSet;` and Bot.letters is also a `Dictionary<char, int[][]>`, but now when i try to access it like this: `letters["A"]`, it says it can't convert string to char.

Comment: Char has single quotes, 'A'